# .Net CurrentCulture ShortDateFormat doesn't update according to PC regional settings

Tags: c#, .net, cultureinfo, regional-settings

I'm configuring a new server and have been experiencing issues with parsing dates where the following code worked perfectly on the old server but not the new server.

```
IFormatProvider fpCanada = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-CA");
Convert.ToDateTime(strStartDate, this.fpCanada); //en-CA
```

> Error: System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

I don't want to have to modify the code to use `TryParseExact` or the registry, so my conclusion was to modify the PC's regional settings to match that of the old server.

**Old server**
Current format: English (Canada)
Short date: dd/MM/yyyy

**New server**
Current format: English (Canada)
Short date: yyyy-MM-DD

After updating the date format of the PC's regional settings to dd/MM/yyyy, I tried resetting the app pool, but that doesn't seem to have done anything.

```
// Still returns yyyy-MM-dd
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern
```

*Am I wrong in assuming that the PC's regional settings have a direct correlation to the `ShortDatePattern` in .Net?*

Comment: Are you talking about the culture on the web server or the client?

Comment: Web server as that's where the code is hosted

Comment: " so my conclusion was to modify the PC's regional settings to match that of the old server." - are you certain that you changed the regional settings system-wide and for all already-existing users? Note that culture settings are also per-user, and if the user account already exists then the old settings still apply until you delete or update that user's registry file. Remember that the user-account the application pool runs under is its own Windows User, even if it doesn't appear in the Users control panel (e.g. Service Identities).

Comment: You are correct, modifying the registry solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

[PC Regional and Language Settings are being ignored in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12619320/pc-regional-and-language-settings-are-being-ignored-in-net)

> I suspect you are running the application under an identity without its own profile, and it is using the default regional settings stored in the registry under 'HKEY_USERS.Default\Control Panel\International`.